# C stdlib .h's on C++ and malloc/realloc

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, include

I was really bothered by the inclusion of **C stdlib** functions on the **global namespace** and ended up writing things like ::snprintf or ::errno or struct ::stat, etc, to differentiate from some of my own functions in the enclosing namespace where those c stdlib functions were used.

Then I discovered that there is a way to declare every C stdlib function in the std namespace (as STL): just include < c(lib) > instead of < (lib).h > so I've edited my code the use those new "c for c++" includes.

On **Debian/GCC 4.3.4** I had to 2 problems:

**1)** #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming \
ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be \
enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.

**2)** using -std=c++0x my program compiles just fine, but I have not modified ::snprintf or ::time, etc.. every C stdlib function is still on the global namespace =(! (no, I'm not *using namespace std* not even once)

Any thoughts?

For example.. how to stop the c stdlib from invading my global namespace? < c(lib) > is an experimental feature of the next C++ standard or could be used safely right now?

Then I've another doubt that perhaps deserves a new question.. there is no cmalloc. I know the whole history about new replacing malloc and why. but for simple plain byte buffers there is no c++ equivalent of **realloc**. I know that memory blocks and reallocation are implementation/so specific, but when there are contiguous free blocks of memory realloc works better than a new buffer allocation and memory copy.

Thanks =)!

Comment: Why do you have other `snprintf` functions and the like?

Comment: For that matter, why do you use `snprintf` at all in a C++ program?

Comment: @jalf: Because it's cleaner, more readable and much faster then C++ streams?

Comment: tomekszpakowicz is correct.. I don't think I need C++ streams to work with and manipulate byte buffers. I just use snprintf to do string/int conversions.. something that I understand it's used anyway in the internals of the stream implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your first question, it depends on which headers you are trying to include. Most of the C headers are available in the `c(lib)` form in the existing version of C++. A few aren't, and may be added in C++0x. So if you tried to include any of those, you might have gotten that error.

Second, all the headers of this form *guarantee* that the functions will be made available in the `std` namespace. But they do not promise to leave the global namespace alone. Often, they put the symbols in both namespaces.

I'm not sure why `::snprintf` bothers you more than `std::snprintf` though. You have to specify a prefix in both cases.

As for `realloc`, a C++ equivalent doesn't exist, probably because it's more trouble than it's worth, especially with C++'s more complicated semantics for copying objects. (In particular, if you try to use it, don't store any non-POD objects in the buffer, as `realloc` will just `memcpy` them to a newly allocated buffer if necessary, which will break non-POD objects.)

Of course, you can still use the old `realloc` from C by including its header. But I'd say you're probably better off using new/delete, and simply figuring out a sensible buffer allocation strategy.

Comment: I believe that all C90 headers are in fact available as `c...` in C++03. The only new stuff in C++0x are some C99 headers.

Comment: "if you try to use it, don't store any non-POD objects in the buffer" - I don't think that "this doesn't play well with placement new" necessarily implies "this is more trouble than it's worth". But every time you think you need `realloc` you should probably stop to work out exactly what it is about each of `vector` and `deque` that fails to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 4):

The `malloc()` function, in standard C is not declared in the "`<malloc.h>`" header. It is declared in `<stdlib.h>`. Same for `realloc()` and `free()`.

I don't know about C++, but instead of

```
#include <cmalloc>
```

try

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

Answer (score 0):

c<lib>, which roughly encloses <lib>.h in a `namespace std { }`, is a standard feature of C++. See §17.4.1.2 if you have access to either standard.

This is not an experimental feature at all -- what header file is giving you the compatibility problems?

Using malloc et al. is fine, but be sure never to mix them with new/delete. (e.g. don't `delete` a `malloc()`'ed buffer.)

Answer (score 0):

There are some of the standard C <lib.h> headers which are not yet transfered to <clib>. Probably you used <cstdint> or the like somewhere.

With the current standard you have the c libraries listed [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/). Note that <cstdint> is **not** part of it.

I didn't find a reference describing if and when <cstdint> will be part of c++, but if I try to include it, I also get an error message telling me I should use -std=c++0x, so I assume it is planned to be included in the next c++ standard.

Comment: Reference? They should all be there.

Comment: Stackoverflow killed the words, which where enclosed in angle brackets. Sorry, fixed it.

Comment: Well, so just use <stdint.h> instead. Or the C++0x switch.